# Why does my algorithm solution fail validation?

Tags: algorithm

Here is a task i got:
Cards are laid out on the table in a row, each card has a natural number written on it. In one move, it is allowed to take a card either from the left or from the right end of the row. In total, you can make k moves. The final score is equal to the sum of the numbers on the selected cards. Determine what is the maximum score you can get at the end of the game.

Here`s my code:

```
def card_counter(arr, k):
    if len(arr) == k:
        return sum(arr)
    rang = len(arr) // 2
    left = arr[:rang]
    right = list(reversed(arr[rang:]))
    c = 0
    for _ in range(k):
        min_arr = left if sum(left) >= sum(
            right) and len(left) > 0 else right
        c += min_arr.pop(0)
    return c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert card_counter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5) == 15
    assert card_counter([0, 0, 0], 1) == 0
    assert card_counter([150], 1) == 150
```

This code works on all variants that I have come up with, including extreme cases. But the system does not accept this option, automatic tests do not pass. Where can there be a mistake?

Comment: You haven't tested your code.

Comment: Which cases should i test?

Comment: Test an array of 10 random unsorted numbers with k=7

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on the algorithm you implemented as you did not state it in non-algorithm terms and I am not familiar with the language you are using (which I am guessing is Python). I will present a simple solution written in Ruby, hoping that the description I give will make it understood by readers who do not know Ruby.

Suppose

```
deck = [1, 2, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 3]
nbr_moves = 4

ds = deck.size
  #=> 8
```

After removing `nbr_moves` from the ends,

```
m = ds - nbr_moves
  #=> 4
```

consecutive cards will remain. In Ruby we could write

```
best = (0..ds-1).each_cons(m).max_by { |arr| deck.values_at(*arr).sum }
   #=> [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

to obtain the indices of `deck`, for which the sum of the associated values is maximum:

```
deck.values_at(*best).sum 
  #=> 18
```

where

```
deck.values_at(*best)
  #=> [7, 1, 4, 6]
```

---

In view of the value of `best` (`[3, 4, 5, 6]`), we need to remove `left = best.first #=> 3` elements from the left and `nbr_moves - left #=> 1` element from the right. The order of the removals is not relevant.

---

Note that

```
enum = (0..ds-1).each_cons(m)
  #=> #<Enumerator: 0..7:each_cons(4)>
```

returns an *enumerator*. We can convert this enumerator to an array to see the values it will generate.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

When, for example,

```
arr = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

then

```
a = deck.values_at(*arr)
  #=> [5, 7, 1, 4]
a.sum
  #=> 17
```

---

Note that, having computed, for example,

```
t = [deck[i], deck[i+1],..., deck[j]].sum
```

the sum of

```
[deck[i+1], deck[i+2],..., deck[j+1]]
```

is seen to equal

```
t - deck[i] + deck[j+1]
```

This suggests a more efficient way to perform the calculations when `m` is large.